# "406 Not Acceptable" for file upload in RoR with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

Tis is my view:

```
<%= form_for item, :url => comment_item_path(item), :html => {:remote => true, 'portal-transform' => true, :multipart => true} do |f| -%>
    <%= f.fields_for :updates, Update.new, :index => nil do |m| -%>
        <%= m.text_area :comment %><br />
        <%= m.file_field :attachment %>
    <% end -%>
    <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
<% end -%>
```

And controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :json => {}
  end
end
```

When I submit the form with only `comment` (text_area) field entered and keep `attachment` (file_field) field blank, it render exactly what expected.
But when I submit the form with `attachment`, it resulted in:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 56ms
```

What went wrong for me? Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html could help

Comment: Could you show the rest of the controller action?

Comment: @polarblau: Nothing. this is the only code inside `def` (only for testing the action, for now)

Comment: So, the item is just sent into nirvana for now? — 406 usually indicates an issue with the (response) format, but I just can't see how in this case…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers do not allow file uploads via AJAX for security reasons. If you leave the form's file_field blank however, the form submits normally with no error, which explains the behaviour you are seeing.

To upload files via AJAX in Rails 3, you can use the Remotipart gem.

http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/

Here is an example usage:

http://thechangelog.com/post/7576700785/remotipart-rails-3-ajax-file-uploads-made-easy